# Cannot use instr in a substr in sql query

Tags: sql, versant-vod

I am using a `sql utility` which integrated in `Solaris 10`.
I want get a column in a table but it seems my sql utility not allows.

Below is my code

```
SELECT
    DBExternalAlarm.m_ObjectDN,
    INSTR(DBExternalAlarm.m_ObjectDN,'@@',30),
    SUBSTR(DBExternalAlarm.m_ObjectDN,1,INSTR(DBExternalAlarm.m_ObjectDN,'@@',30))
FROM DBExternalAlarm;
```

Result have only 2 data columns

```
- DBExternalAlarm.m_ObjectDN
- INSTR(DBExternalAlarm.m_ObjectDN,'@@',30)
```

I don't know, any body can give other way to resolve this.
Can I using a varible or other function?

Comment: So you're saying that the query ran, without error, but only returned two columns?  Are you sure this is reproducible?

Comment: Yes, when I replace INSTR(DBExternalAlarm.m_ObjectDN,'@@',30) with a number, column has data.

Answer (score 0):

My guess here is there *is* a third column being returned in your result set, but it is just empty string, because `@@` is not being found, starting at the 30th position.  To test this hypothesis, use the following query:

```
SELECT
    DBExternalAlarm.m_ObjectDN,
    INSTR(DBExternalAlarm.m_ObjectDN,'@@',30),
    CASE WHEN INSTR(DBExternalAlarm.m_ObjectDN,'@@',30) > 0
         THEN SUBSTR(DBExternalAlarm.m_ObjectDN, 1,
             INSTR(DBExternalAlarm.m_ObjectDN,'@@',30))
         ELSE 'Not Found' END AS result
FROM DBExternalAlarm;
```

I don't know your database, but in Oracle `INSTR` will return 0 if the string is not found.  The above `CASE` expression checks for this and outputs `Not Found` in this case.  If you see this everywhere, then you'll know that there are no matches.

Comment: I checked my data with many string @@ at position 44th 45th of record. Also I tried replace  INSTR(DBExternalAlarm.m_ObjectDN,'@@',30)  with number 44, the result ok

Comment: What does my query output, if anything?